# using on SQLDataReader

Tags: c#, dispose, sqldatareader, using-statement

I know I asked a related question earlier. I just had another thought.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection('blah blah'))
{
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, conn))
    {
        conn.open();

        // *** do I need to put this in using as well? ***
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader() 
        {
            While(dr.Read())
            {
                //read here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The argument is that: Since the `SqlDataReader` `dr` object is NOT A NEW OBJECT LIKE THE connection or command objects, its simply a reference pointing to the `cmd.ExecuteReader()` method, do I need to put the reader inside a `using`. (Now based on my previous post, it is my understanding that any object that uses `IDisposable` needs to be put in a `using`, and `SQLDataReader` inherits from `IDisposable`, so I need to put it. Am I correct in my judgement?) I am just confused since its not a new object, would it cause any problems in disposing an object that simply is a reference pointer to the command?

Many thanks

Comment: "cmd.ExecuteReader" is a sort of method reference. "cmd.ExecuteReader()" (notice brackets) is a method call.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think you are mistaken.  The `dr` is a reference to the object returned by `cmd.ExecuteReader`, which is going to be a new object.  In your example, nothing will dispose `dr`, so yes it needs to be in a `using`, or manually disposed.

Your judgement about `IDisposable` implementors *needing* to be in a `using` is not correct.  They will function fine outside.  A `using` statement is just syntactic sugar for a `try ... finally`.  Things implementing `IDisposable` should have `Dispose` called, because they are signalling that they need to dispose certain state in a deterministic way.

Note that if you do not call `Dispose`, its not always a problem.  Some objects also implement the finalizer, which will be triggered by the garbage collector.  If they do not implement the finalizer, they might leave unmanaged memory unreclaimed.  This will remain unreclaimed until your application closes.  All managed memory is eventually reclaimed, unless it is not elligible for garbage collection.

Re-written:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection('blah blah')) 
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, conn)) 
{
   conn.open(); 
   using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
   { 
        while (dr.Read()) 
        { 
           //read here 
        } 
   } 
}
```

Comment: yes i understand that the using simply translates into a try..finally block and I could just as well call the dispose my self. But I think its better to make a habit of wrapping the block inside the using as I could tend to forget putting the chunk of code in try..finnally. Thanks for the reply. :)

Comment: That's OK :-) I'll mention it as well that the SqlDataReader is a new object, or is at least a reference to an object returned by the method call, it is not a reference to the method. Just mentioning because you made that point in capital letters and its not correct.  The only difference between the reader and the connection/command is that you initialized the connection/command, but you did not initialize the reader.  At the end you still have references to all objects - whether you initialized them or not.

Comment: Maybe this goes without saying, but `conn.Close();` is needed after the `using(SqlDataReader dr=cmd.ExecuteReader()) { ... }` section, correct?

Comment: @TrevorNestman Close is called on dispose, but you can call it explicitly too if you wish.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Thanks for the response/info! I'm pretty new to SqlConnection, so I'm trying to use it properly.

Answer (score 2):

You should wrap the data reader in a using statement as the ExecuteReader method is creating a new data reader instance that should also be disposed of.