# Simple update MySQL C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I have simple code for insert in database and it works fine;

```
static public void InsertUser(string userName, int age, DataGridView DadataGridView1)
    {
        try
        {
            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                connection.Open();
            MySqlCommand commandInsert = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO IP(Username,Age) VALUES(@Username,@Age)", connection);
            commandInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", userName);
            commandInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", age);
            commandInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
            commandInsert.Parameters.Clear();
            MessageBox.Show("User Inserted sucessfuly");
        }
        catch (MySqlException exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exception.ToString());

        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();

        }
    }
```

I need write code for UPDATE and GET data.
Please advice, I am a beginner in C #.
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to directly execute SQL query in C#? Have example batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21709305/how-to-directly-execute-sql-query-in-c-have-example-batch-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope that you may have a primary key for this table,You can use  [`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) so that you need not to write different query for update. if the Key is duplicate(existing) the the value get updated. so your command will be like the following:

```
   MySqlCommand commandInsert = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO IP(Username,Age) VALUES(@Username,@Age) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Username=VALUES(Username),Age=VALUES(Age)", connection);
```