# Getting SQL to work from C# with Dates

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a simple SQL query that works in SQL:

```
 select txdate, acct from trans where txdate = '1/31/2017'
```

I cannot get it to work from C#:

```
  DateTime sDate = dtStart.Value;  // date time picker
  // connect to server
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select txdate from trans where txdate = '@sdate'", cx);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sdate", sDate);
  var retVal = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

var always returns -1 when it returns a set of records in SQLServer.  I've been on this for hours.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is in a loop that increments days.  My objective is to get the results of the first date.  I've tried no quotes and it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Get the results of the query? Use [`ExecuteReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k(v=vs.110).aspx) instead. Also your parameter shouldn't have single quotes round it.

Comment: Look on this http://stackoverflow.com/a/21709663/5888230 I hope this can help you

Comment: Also how many rows are there in trans per date? Do  you really need multiple identical rows returned by `select txdate from trans where txdate =` or just the count?

Comment: `ExecuteNonQuery` doesnt return data, but rows affected (for updates, inserts, deletes). It *may* always return `-1` even when rows were affected. It depends on configuration (`set nocount` in particular). Don't use `AddWithValue`. To select data, use `ExecuteReader` or `ExecuteScalar` depending on your needs. Remove the quotes around `@sdate`.

Comment: I think @pinkfloydx33 called it -- Remove the quotes around `@sdate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `ExecuteScalar()` only returns the value from the first column of the
>   first row of your query. `ExecuteReader()` returns an object that can
>   iterate over the entire result set. `ExecuteNonQuery()` does not
>   return data at all: only the number of rows affected by an insert,
>   update, or delete.

in your case you are trying to get data not inset update or delete that is why `ExecuteNonQuery()` is returning `-1` because no row is affected. so you can use `ExecuteScalar()` like

```
 DateTime sDate = dtStart.Value;  // date time picker
  // connect to server
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select txdate from trans where txdate = @sdate", cx);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sdate", sDate);
  var result = (DateTime)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

if you are returning multiple values then you should use `SqldataAdapter` or `ExecuteReader()`

Comment: When I use var retVal = (DateTime)cmd.ExecuteScalar();, I keep getting : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: I put it in a try block incrementing the date until it is the first known date and it works now.