# how to take values to the variable from the query "select sum(items)from tb_checkout group by name,category") in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

how to take values to the variable from the query

```
DataTable dt=cs.selectquery("select sum(items)from tb_checkout group by name,category")
```

in Asp.net?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to directly execute SQL query in C#? Have example batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21709305/how-to-directly-execute-sql-query-in-c-have-example-batch-file)