# Visual Studio 2019: run SQL query in C# with parameter coming from web form

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, visual-studio-2019

I am totally new to ASP.NET and C#, and I am designing a web form. The user gives me some inputs, let's say `keyvalue`, and I have to query a database using that parameter.

[I have seen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21709663/5490188) that it's possible to run a SQL query inside C#. In that example, however, the query string is fixed:

```
string queryString = "SELECT * FROM This.Table WHERE keyvalue = 'WINNIPEG'"
```

What if my `keyvalue` comes from user input instead? Can I do something like:

```
string keyvalue = txtInputCell.Text
string queryString = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE key = keyvalue"
```

Comment: There are a *lot* of ASP.NET and  ADO.NET tutorials that show how to handle user input and how to execute a query. Every `Getting Started` tutorial in learn.microsoft.com shows how to read data from forms and how to call the database. Which stack are you using? WebForms? ASP.NET MVC? Razor Pages?

Comment: This is an empty page built as a web form.