# update multiple rows using list of id in c#

Tags: c#, database

I'm having list of ids and I want to update the database table. I'm doing something like this:

```
sql = "update table set col = 'something' where id in (@Ids)"

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connection)){
   connection.Query(sql, new { Ids = ids});
}
```

The error is:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near ','.'

Comment: There's plenty examples out there of how to do this. [Here's one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21709305/how-to-directly-execute-sql-query-in-c/21709663)

Answer (score 1):

the simpleset way is this:

```
var parameters = new string[ids.Length];
var cmd = new SqlCommand();
for (int i = 0; i < ids.Length; i++)
{
    parameters[i] = string.Format("@Id{0}", i);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameters[i], ids[i]);
}

  cmd.CommandText = string.Format("update table set col = 'something' where id in ({0})", string.Join(", ", parameters));
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution : This is working for me

```
sql = "update table set col = 'something' where id in ("+string.Join(",", ids) + ");";

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connection)){
   connection.Query(sql);
}
```

Comment: Don't use string concatenation to build SQL Query, it causes SQL Injections. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work