# Convert string to FormattableString in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, formattablestring

I am trying to build a website vulnerable to SQL injections (for educational purposes) with an ASP.NET API. To do that, I would like to call `FromSql` with a previously prepared SQL query as such:

```cs
String query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '"+email
                  +"' AND password = '"+password+"'";
return RepositoryContext.Users.FromSql(query).FirstOrDefault();
```

But this code will not compile as `FromSql` is expecting a `FormattableString`, and not a `String`. I get the following error message:

> Error CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.FormattableString'

The following would compile, but then this code would not be vulnerable to SQL injections anymore as Entity Framework will perform a prepared SQL query and convert email and password to SQL query parameters :

```cs
return RepositoryContext.Users.FromSql(
   $"SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = {email} 
                           AND password = {password}").FirstOrDefault();
```

Is there a way to convert a `String` to a `FormattableString`?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Since you only want it for demonstration, I'd suggest to use a direct SQL connection. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21709305/how-to-directly-execute-sql-query-in-c
You can directly manipulate the string and can put a malicious query there. I think EF does a good job in preventing SQL injection out of the box

Answer (score 11):

using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

...

```
var s = "...";
var fs = FormattableStringFactory.Create(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you see is Entity Framework doing a good job at preventing SQL injection by default.

You can teach SQL injection by using the [FromSqlRaw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalqueryableextensions.fromsqlraw) method instead which takes a string that could be maliciously crafted.

See also Entity Framework Core [SQL Queries → Passing parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries#passing-parameters) documentation:

> **Pay close attention to parameterization when using SQL queries**
>
> When introducing any user-provided values into a SQL query, care must be taken to avoid SQL injection attacks. SQL injection occurs when a program integrates a user-provided string value into a SQL query, and the user-provided value is crafted to terminate the string and perform another malicious SQL operation. To learn more about SQL injection, [see this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/sql-injection).
>
> The [FromSql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalqueryableextensions.fromsql) and [FromSqlInterpolated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalqueryableextensions.fromsqlinterpolated) methods are safe against SQL injection, and always integrate parameter data as a separate SQL parameter. However, the [FromSqlRaw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalqueryableextensions.fromsqlraw) method can be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, if improperly used. See below for more details.